# PHP Google API OAuth2 JWT request for new acces token says "invalid_grant"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

In short, I want to obtain a new acces token with a service account on Google API. I used OAuth 2.0 and a JWT request. I found many similar post, but non of them answered my question. I done everything conform to the [Google OAuth 2.0 Server-to-Server request guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but when i send the POST request, i get in return "invalid_grant". Any ideas why? Here is my code:

```php
$jwt_header_array =     array(  "alg"       => "RS256",
                                    "typ"       => "JWT");

    $jwt_claim_array =      array(  "iss"       => "upload-file@feedking-1355.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                                    "scope"     => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                                    "aud"       => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                                    "exp"       => time()+3600,
                                    "iat"       => time());

    $jwt_header = base64_encode(json_encode($jwt_header_array));
    $jwt_claim = base64_encode(json_encode($jwt_claim_array));

    $key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- privat_key_downloaded_from_google_console -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

    $pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);
    openssl_sign($jwt_header.'.'.$jwt_claim, $jwt_signature, $pkeyid, "sha256");
    $jwt_signature = base64_encode($jwt_signature);

    $jwt = $jwt_header.'.'.$jwt_claim.'.'.$jwt_signature;

    echo $jwt.'<br /><br />';

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
    $query = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='.$jwt;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: technically you need to base64url-encode the JWT elements instead of just base64 encoding them

Comment: Those encodings are good, because i get the correct JWT header and claim as within the example at Google, with the same inputs from that example. The only problem is with the signature, which I cannot verify, because the key is different from what in the example is used.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution, and it was ridiculously obvious. Why not using Google Utils, Auth and Signer/P12 classes? You can get the whole package with composer (google/apiclient), beside you will need this for making Google API authentication (in fact i already had this package, dumb me). I will guide you through the whole process:

**NEW SOLUTION:**

You will need the Google API package and the Google Service account as described in the old solution below (stage 1, 2, 3). From here just copy-paste the fully API based code and replace the input datas:

```php
$client_email = 'file-upload-final@feedking-1355.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('p12_final.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
     $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
```

**OLD SOLUTION:**

1. Create a [Google Service account](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/), since this is essential to access Google APIs without further user consent. Make sure that when you create it, you check "Furnish new private key" and "P12" options. Check other options as well if needed.
2. Download, upload the P12 file to your server / local, and store the password (its usually "notasecret" at this time...).
3. Install the Google API package with composer or GIT, if you don't have already. I prefer composer because the GIT version lacks some libraries, for me the Client class was a bit buggy (could be my fault of course).
4. You just have to use the right classes to make and encode the JWT header and playload, and sign the certificate. Take care of the P12 certificate path and for the corrent inputs in the playload (you can get all of it from the [Google Developer Console Credetials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) page, and you can also get informations about values on [Google OAuth 2.0 Server-to-Server Application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) page). Here is the code:

```php
$header = array("typ" => "JWT", 
                "alg" => "RS256");

$playload = array(  "iss"       => "upload-file2@feedking-1355.iam.gserviceaccount.com", 
                    "scope"     => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                    "aud"       => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                    "exp"       => time()+3600,
                    "iat"       => time());

$segments = array();
$segments[] = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode(json_encode($header));
$segments[] = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode(json_encode($playload));
$signing_input = implode(".", $segments);
$signer = new Google_Signer_P12(file_get_contents('p12.p12', true), 'notasecret');
$signature = $signer->sign($signing_input);
$segments[] = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode($signature);
$jwt = implode(".", $segments);
```

5. Send the request with cURL or whatever you want to get the Access token:

```php
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
$query = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='.$jwt;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

6. Finally the var_dump($result) output should be something similar:

string(141) "{ "access_token": "ya29.Ci8QAzKz-U83RiaylDKgSDgH9XEVQrdBAQ5EBxMFUncN7WLfeGan0BCMJRdFJykC-g", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3600 } "

Hope you enjoyed it and will upvote, since i messed up 2 days with this authentication story. Google API can do magic in some cases, so it's an essential thing to learn inmho.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one small problem in your code and it will be working perfectly… native php `base64_encode()` it's bit different than API's expecting `base64_url_encode()`

code looks like this:

```php
function base64_url_encode(string $input) : string
{
    return str_replace('=', '', strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_'));
}
```

**and everything will work fine.**

I know it's been years (from question) and Google created libraries which can be easilly downloaded&installed by `Composer` but…
In my case I need to get visites by last 7 days from GA. With original libraries from Google i can do it. But it's 66.8 MB of files, just for this little problem.

I know there's a lot of usefull libraries as well, but I don't need them. I need just visites by last 7 days from GA. And that's what I can do with native PHP and OpenSSL functionst … about 1 kB of code.